# How do I add a hyperlink with spaces in it using markdown?

Tags: url, markdown

Been trying to add a link on Trello to a bookmarked destination in a PDF using markdown.

I'm appending

```
 #nameddest=this destination
```

to the end of my URLs to add a reference to a specific spot in the document, but the space breaks the link. Is it possible to create a link with spaces?

Comment: do you need the `#nameddest=url` syntax?  can you use `[text](url)` instead?  what about direct html `<a href="url">text</a>`?  (into what software are you inputting the markdown?  it may use a weird flavor of markdown that needs special formatting.)

Answer (score 43):

According to [*CommonMark*](https://commonmark.org/)<sup>1</sup>, you can use links with spaces as long as the URL is wrapped in angle brackets e.g.

```
[Link caption](<https://duckduckgo.com/?q=test this!&t=ffab>)
```

<sup>1: The minimum common denominator that all Markdown flavours are to support.  I see the StackExchange's implementation doesn't support it.  Sigh!</sup>

Comment: Works with GitHub's markdown

Answer (score 12):

I'd [urlencode](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) the link `#nameddest=this%20destination` instead of `#nameddest=this destination`.

Just tried in Trello linking [like this](https://www.google.com/search?q=my%20query) works for me:
`[like this](https://www.google.com/search?q=my%20query)`

If you want to URL to be linked just make it
`[https://www.google.com/search?q=my%20query](https://www.google.com/search?q=my%20query)`

Comment: Tried this, but it does not work for some reason. Also tried enclosing the link in carrots and parentheses and using a '+' instead of a space.

Comment: @JohnFukuyama just tried in Trello, worked for me – see update in my answer.

Comment: tnx, this worked in gitlab markdown for me

Comment: To me, this solution is much better. I try "<>" but fails on some browser.